# mkfifo make 2 processes talk to each other

Tags: c, ipc, mkfifo

I am trying to write 2 programs that will talk to each other using fifo pipe.
I used the example [here](https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/#producers-and-consumers) (section 5.2), but I changed the mknod there to mkfifo and tried to change gets to fgets.
This is the code (of one program which writes into the fifo):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h> /*mkfifo, open */
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> /* mkfifo, open */
#include <fcntl.h> /*open */

#define FIFO_PATH "/home/hana/Desktop"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 300



int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int fd;
    int wStatus;
    
    mkfifo(FIFO_PATH, 666);
    printf("waiting for readers\n");
    fd = open(FIFO_PATH, O_RDWR);
    
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fd), !feof(stdin)) 
    {
        if ((wStatus = write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer))) == -1)
            perror("write");
        else
            printf("speak: wrote %d bytes\n", wStatus);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error: passing argument 3 of fgets makes pointer from integer.
So fgets is expecting FILE* and not file descriptor.
What should I do? change something so that fgets works? use another function?

I am compiling with gcc (ansi, pedantic).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkfifo()` just creates special node in filesystem. And you are free to open it in any way. Actually there are two alternatives - POSIX "non-buffered" I/O: `open()/write()/read()` or standard buffered I/O: `fopen()/fread()/fwrite()`. First family operates on file descriptors while second one uses so called file streams: `FILE`. You can not mix these APIs freely. Just choose one and stick to it.
Standard I/O library offers some useful extra capabilities comparing to low-level non-buffered I/O. Like `fgets()` that you're trying to use. In this situation would be reasonable to use standard streams and replace `open()` with:

```
FILE* stream = fopen(FIFO_PATH, "r+");
```

Thus program will use `FILE*` instead of plain file descriptors. Also `write()` need to be changed to `fwrite()` immediately followed by `fflush()` to guarantee that written data are passed to FIFO.

P.S. In case of necessity it is possible to "wrap" low-level descriptors returned by `open()`(or something other) with standard `FILE*`. See [`fdopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3p.html). But it is much like a workaround to use standard I/O API with special file objects that can not be opened with `fopen()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from whjm is the cause of your error diagnostic, but I think you probably meant

```
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)
//                         ^^^^^
```

It doesn't make sense that you would read from a pipe and then immediately write the same thing back to the pipe. Also, if you never read from `stdin`, `feof(stdin)` will never be true.

Also, with fgets just check for a null result and then outside the loop, do the check for eof:

```
while (fgets(...) != NULL)
{
    ...
}
if (!feof(stdin))
{
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: i did not really read the code since the OP's only asking about the compilation error and how to get a `FILE *`. :)

Comment: @whjm I am not implying your answer was wrong. In fact your up vote is mine.

Comment: i also changed the subject and removed tags `ipc` and `mkinfo`. just rolled back. :)